# Failed pip install mysql-python

Tags: mysql-python

I am running this in Windows environment using python version 2.7, while running below will give error, running pip install mysql-python for the testproject will give similiar error too. I tried download and run installer from http://www.codegood.com/archives/4, but it says python version 2.6 required but not found in registry. Some resources say mysql_config file is missing, is this the case?

```
C:\django\testproject\build\MySQL-python>setup.py build
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\django\testproject\build\MySQL-python\setup.py", line 1

    metadata, options = get_config()
  File "C:\django\testproject\build\MySQL-python\setup_windows.py"
et_config
    serverKey = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, option
y'])
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Answer (score 2):

You might find what you need here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python

It has a precompiled version for Python 2.7

Comment: Thanks. I downgraded to python 2.6 then it seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing using an executable?

MySQL-python 1.2.5 MS Windows installer can be found [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.5) and is easily the easiest way for windows.

*In [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/files/) you have a sourceforge repository with execs for other MySQL-python versions in case that doesn't work.