# python mysql installation failed

Tags: python, mysql, database, pip

When I tried to install `mysql` in python

using this command `python -m pip install mysql`

can anyone help me with this?

> Collecting mysql   Using cached mysql-0.0.1.tar.gz Collecting
>   MySQL-python (from mysql)   Using cached MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
>   Installing collected packages: MySQL-python, mysql   Running setup.py
>   install for MySQL-python ... error
>       Complete output from command C:\Users\vishnuvardhan12137\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe
>   -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\VISHNU~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-lw04ypbu\MySQL-python\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record C:\Users\VISHNU~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-0awclynb-record\install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
>       running install
>       running build
>       running build_py
>       creating build
>       creating build\lib.win32-3.6
>       copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6
>       creating build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb
>       copying MySQLdb__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb
>       copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb
>       copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb
>       copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb
>       copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb
>       copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb
>       creating build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
>       copying MySQLdb\constants__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
>       copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
>       copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
>       copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
>       copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
>       copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
>       copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
>       running build_ext
>       building '_mysql' extension
>       error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools":
>   http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools
>
> ---------------------------------------- Command "C:\Users\vishnuvardhan12137\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe
>   -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\VISHNU~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-lw04ypbu\MySQL-python\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record C:\Users\VISHNU~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-0awclynb-record\install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in
>   C:\Users\VISHNU~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-lw04ypbu\MySQL-python\

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error while installing lxml through pip: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38949519/error-while-installing-lxml-through-pip-microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed pip install mysql-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9077890/failed-pip-install-mysql-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says that it requires Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0. Have you tried installing that version of Microsoft Visual C++? And do take a look at this post too. [Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)

Answer (score 0):

Go to this website:
https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient

Get your compatible mysqlclient version as per python version and windows version 32/64 bit then run following command

`pip install mysqlclient-1.4.2-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl`

in my case it was `python 3.7` and `32-bit Windows` so I downloaded such file `mysqlclient-1.4.2-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl`